# web2py-ckeditor how to display the rich text created by ckeditor instead of the html tags

Tags: ckeditor, web2py, rich-text-editor, web2py-modules

I am using web2py with ckeditor.I want to input rich text into the database with SQLFORM. So I choose ckeditor as a field widget. I have installed the ckeditor and here is my db.py:

```
from plugin_ckeditor import CKEditor
ckeditor = CKEditor(db)
db.define_table("comtable",
            Field("com_name",label="name"),
            Field("com_property",label="property",requires=IS_IN_SET(['A', 'B', 'C',"D"])),Field("com_detail",label="info",type="text",widget=ckeditor.widget))
```

and the following is my default.py/index:

```
def index():
    form=SQLFORM(db.comtable,fields = ['com_name',"com_property","com_detail"])
    gridform=SQLFORM.smartgrid(db.comtable)
    if form.process().accepted:
        response.flash="OK"
    return dict(form=form,gridform=gridform)
```

and the following is my index.html:

```
{{=form}}
{{=gridform}}
```

After I have input some information into the text with ckeditor widget the record is displayed by the SQLFORM.smartgrid like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLAsS.png)

When I click the "view" button I get the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrlUC.png)

I don't want to display the text with html tags. I want to get the rich text. Could any one tell me what should I do or need I choose another rich text editor?

With help of the following method you told me the rich text can be displayed when I click the "view" button. However the HTML tags codes are displayed when I click the "edit" button. Is there any method to show the rich text when I click the "edit" button? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, all data included in a view is escaped (for security purposes). To override this, you can wrap the content in the `XML()` helper. To make this automatic, you can do it by specifying a `represent` attribute for the relevant field:

```
Field('com_detail', label='info', type='text', widget=ckeditor.widget,
      represent=lambda content, row: XML(content, sanitize=True))
```

The `represent` function controls how the field values will be displayed in `SQLTABLE`, `SQLFORM.grid`, read-only `SQLFORM`s, and when using the `Rows.render` method.

The `sanitize=True` option limits the allowed HTML tags and attributes to minimize the security risk of including user-supplied markup in a page. See the [documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#XML) for details on customizing the allowed tags and attributes.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. It's really very kind of you, Anthony

Comment: Hi, Anthony. According to the above method the rich text can be displayed when I click the "view" button. However the HTML tags codes are displayed when I click the "edit" button. Is there any method to show the rich text when I click the "edit" button? Thank you very much.